# SQL Add primary key + number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have primary key field with auto increment name BoxID 
And I have a blank field name BoxAddNumber 
My goal is to add BoxID + 10 so it can update BoxAddNumber field

```
BoxID      BoxAddNumber
  1           11
  2           12
  3           13
and so on
```

My query

```
UPDATE Inventory SET BoxAddNumber = 'BoxID' + '10'
```

Can someone help me correct this query. Thanks a lot. with auto incremental

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just:

```
UPDATE Inventory SET BoxAddNumber = BoxID + 10
```

Rationale:

- column names should not be surrounded with single quotes; those are meant for litteral strings
- same goes for numbers, which should not be surrounded with strings either

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention

> with auto incremental

I think you want a computed column as

```
EXEC SP_RENAME 'Inventory.BoxAddNumber', 'B', 'COLUMN';

ALTER TABLE
ADD BoxAddNumber AS Id + 10;

ALTER TABLE dbo.Inventory
DROP COLUMN B;
```

If you are just looking for an `UPDATE` then you could go with the other answer.